# Does SQLite3 change databases even if every statement is "SELECT"

Tags: c++, sqlite, windows-7, virtualization

we try to deploy our software on Windows 7, and there are several sqlite3 db files around. But, these are all read-only and we execute only "SELECT" statements. However, we have observed that Windows 7 also make virtualization on these files, which means file structure or content is changed. What do you think of it? What changes these files without any INSERT or UPDATE? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these databases exist in your Program Files folder? If so, you should take a look at e.g. [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx).  Data files shouldn't go in the Program Files folder but in Program Data.  Otherwise, if you really positively absolutely have to put the databases in the Program Files folder, make sure you pass SQLite the proper flags to open it in read-only mode by passing `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` (see [the manual](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)).